# Running php website on Google App Engine Standard doesn't route to subfolders and files

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml, front-controller

I'm trying to migrate our website from a linux vm (also on google) to google App Engine Standard enviroment.

When i deploy the app and test it the main page (index.php) works fine but when i try to go to other files, for example /somefolder/somefile.php it doesnt. It just shows the index.php but without the pictures etc.

I searched the internet and i found that this is probably due to not having a front end controller(?)

My app.yaml file is as followed:

```
service: nameoftheapp
runtime: php83

handlers:
# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: auto

- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

my index.php is:

```
<?php



// android store
if (preg_match('#android#i', $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    header('Location: market://details?id=nl.myapp');
    exit;
}

// ios
if (preg_match('#(iPad|iPhone|iPod)#i', $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    header('Location: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/myapp/id973246494');
    exit;
}
echo "<html> <head> </head> <body>";
echo '<center><p><br><p><br>Sometext</center> <p>';
echo '<center> some more text.</center> <p>';
echo "<center> <img width='800' src='images/logo_GW_forweb.jpg'</center> <p>";
echo "<center> yet some more text</center> <p>";
echo "</body>";

?>
```

the index.php serves as a simple landing page for users to redirect them to the appstores for the app. As far as this goes, this works well. also the logo, which resides in a subfolder is shown.

But i myself want to go to https://mywebsite.nl/somefolder/somefile.php

This part doesnt work. Can this be resolved by just setting the right app.yaml (i do have like 10 subfolders with some having their own subfolders and a total of 100+ .php files)

Do i need something else? I was hoping there would be a settings for the app.yaml that routes all reguests to the right place.

I made a test app to see how to get it working. This one works, but i doubt this is the way to go.

The app.yaml file states:

```
runtime: php83
service: test

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

And the index states:

```
<?php
$requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Hier kun je logica toevoegen om het verzoek te routeren naar de juiste actie/controller
if ($requestUri === '/test/test.php') {
    require 'test/test.php';
} elseif ($requestUri === '/root.php') {
    require 'root.php';
} else {
    // Standaard HTML-tekst als de URI niet overeenkomt met specifieke routes
    echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
    echo "<html lang=\"en\">";
    echo "<head>";
    echo "    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">";
    echo "    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">";
    echo "    <title>Test App</title>";
    echo "</head>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "    <h1>Hallo dit is een test</h1>";
    echo "    <p>Welkom bij de PHP-testapplicatie op Google App Engine!</p>";
    echo "    <p><a href=\"test/test.php\">Ga naar test.php</a></p>";
    echo "    <p><a href=\"root.php\">Ga naar root.php</a></p>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
}
?>
```

This one works. i can access the root.php as well as the test.php which is located in the subfolder test. But i doubt this would be the way to go for my own website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're right that you need a front controller ([ref](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/runtime#app_startup)). Google recommends using a framework like Laravel, Symfony, or Slim.
2. If you would rather use your `index.php` file (instead of a framework) and you also have a lot of sub-paths (sub folders), you should write your front controller code to use regex to detect the routes.

   [This](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/1ec5c14e625ab127d2563b657d5845686e4f5a67/appengine/standard/grpc/index.php#L11) is an example from Google and the use case is similar to yours - user lands on the home page (`index.php`) which has links that take user to other parts of the site

Comment: Thank you for the info. we are no trying to get it working with laravel.