# php app.yaml configuration for google cloud

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gcloud, app.yaml

With the Google update in the app engine for PHP 8.1 it does not allow me to redirect to other scripts, it only accepts the index, the error occurs when validating the session and redirecting to the login, it begins with an endless loop to index .php without entering login.php

I have carried out the validation with JS and with PHP and I have not been able to solve it in either way.

extra info: Static addresses have no problem, they load correctly, the js and css files, as well as the images

I will be very grateful for any clue you can provide me.

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
//validation only for testing
if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])){
    header('location: login.php');
    exit();
  }
?>
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: php81
service: frontdev

handlers:
- url: /bundle
  static_dir: bundle
- url: /img
  static_dir: img
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
- url: /font-awesome
  static_dir: font-awesome
- url: /fonts
  static_dir: fonts
- url: /js
  static_dir: js
- url: /js_sys
  static_dir: js_sys
- url: /nbproject
  static_dir: nbproject
- url: /sound
  static_dir: sound
- url: /views
  static_dir: views
- url: /confapp
  static_dir: confapp
- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets
- url: /ajax
  static_dir: ajax
- url: /helpers
  static_dir: helpers
- url: /
  script: index.php
  secure: always
- url: /login
  script: login.php
  secure: always
- url: /recover
  script: recover_password.php
  secure: always
- url: /reset
  script: resetPassword.php
  secure: always
```

and tried to follow the steps that come in the documentation.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/config/appref?hl=es-419

```
- url: .*
  script: auto

- url: /
  script: index
  secure: always
```

Comment: Take a look at the following SO questions - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77745585/running-php-website-on-google-app-engine-standard-doesnt-route-to-subfolders-an), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77796577/google-app-engine-front-controller-questions)