# Google App Engine - Front controller questions

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

i got an google app engine deployment with 2 php files, index.php and generate.php, when I try to access generate.php, the app engine redirects to index.php always, no matter what i do, no matter what config I do in app.yaml

I still need to understand how app engine works so, does it will allways serve index.php as a front controller, no way to disable that? how can i serve generate.php directly with no redirects?
I just want it to be able to output some text when domain.com/generate.php is being called.
This is hardcoded into my app's already installed users (1m) so changing it to domain.com/c=generate might not be my best option right now.

I tried to modify app.yaml settings with chat gpt suggestions but none worked.

Comment: Is this standard or is it flex env?

Comment: hello! it is standard

Comment: Did you have a look at the dispatch definition? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/dispatch-yaml?tab=python

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/runtime#app_startup)

1. You need a front controller
2. > If your app contains a public/index.php or index.php file, App Engine uses this file to serve your app.

   This means the above will serve as your controller (so it should be coded to behave as one). You can use regex rules (see a [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/add395fbcfb6cc55f3f638b025ddc3d6b6d31f59/appengine/standard/grpc/index.php#L11) from Google)
3. You can also specify a different controller by specifying an `entrypoint` in your `app.yaml` file

   > If you specify the optional entrypoint element in your app.yaml file, App Engine uses the command in the entrypoint element to serve your app instead of using public/index.php or index.php

   So, you can specify your `generate.php` as your entrypoint but it then means all pages will go to it (since you haven't coded it to redirect to others)
4. Google's recommendation is actually to use a framework, such as Laravel, Symfony, or Slim

Comment: Well i guess I've should done that in the first place haha, yes its the way to go! thanks! Gonna look for a light frameworks that adequate to my project.